# Redirect to admin/user page after login

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my page and it works properly, I just want to add how to redirect the the page depending if account is admin or user, please indicate where to add, and if there is any idea on my MySQL database to change, that would be useful.

DATABASE:

```
id_number username password status
1         admin    admin    1
2         user     user     0

admin = 1
user = 0

            <?php 
             // Connects to your Database 
             mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
             mysql_select_db("net25") or die(mysql_error()); 
             //Checks if there is a login cookie
             if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site']))
             //if there is, it logs you in and directes you to the members page
             { 
                $username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 
                $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];
                    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")or die(mysql_error());
                while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))  
                    {
                    if ($pass != $info['password']) 
                        {
                                    }
                    else
                        {
                        header("Location: main.php");
                        }
                    }
             }
             //if the login form is submitted 
             if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // if form has been submitted
             // makes sure they filled it in
                if(!$_POST['username'] | !$_POST['pass']) {
                    die('You did not fill in a required field.');
                }
                // checks it against the database
                if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                }
                $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."'")or die(mysql_error());
             //Gives error if user dosen't exist
             $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);
             if ($check2 == 0) {
                    die('That user does not exist in our database. <a href=register.php>Click Here to Register</a>');
                            }
             while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))     
             {
             $_POST['pass'] = stripslashes($_POST['pass']);
                $info['password'] = stripslashes($info['password']);
                $_POST['pass'] = md5($_POST['pass']);
             //gives error if the password is wrong
                if ($_POST['pass'] != $info['password']) {
                    die('Incorrect password, please try again. <a href=index.php>Click Here to Log In</a>');
                }
                else 
             { 
             // if login is ok then we add a cookie 
                 $_POST['username'] = stripslashes($_POST['username']); 
                 $hour = time() + 3600; 
             setcookie(ID_my_site, $_POST['username'], $hour); 
             setcookie(Key_my_site, $_POST['pass'], $hour);  
             //then redirect them to the members area 
             header("Location: main.php"); 
             } 
             } 
             } 
             else 
            {    
             // if they are not logged in 
             ?> 
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post"> 
             <table border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' bordercolor='#FF9900' bgcolor="#CCFFFF"> 
             <tr><td colspan=2><h1>Login</h1></td></tr> 
             <tr><td>Username:</td><td> 
             <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="40"> 
             </td></tr> 
             <tr><td>Password:</td><td> 
             <input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="50"> 
             </td></tr> 
             <tr><td colspan="2" align="right"> 
             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"> 
             </td></tr> 
             </table> 
             <br />
             <a href="/hrd/orig/register.php">Register Here</a>
            </form> 
             <?php 
             } 
             ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($info['status'] == '1') { // check the value of the 'status' in the db
    //go to admin area
    header("Location: admin.php");
} else {
    //go to members area
    header("Location: main.php");  
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: thanks for the reply, where should i put that? sorry for being innocent

Comment: right where the original redirect is, so replace your `header("Location: main.php");` with my piece and you should be good to go

Answer (score 2):

I would add the additional redirects near the original line:

```
header("Location: main.php");
```

Probably in an if statement like this:

```
if($info['status'])
{
    header("Location: admin.php");
}
else
{
    header("Location: main.php");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a user define in the database define an "Authentication" of 0 or 1. Then when they log in you can do something like.

logincheckpage.php

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_name='$myusername' and p_word='$encrypted_p_word'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row= mysql_fetch_array($result);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
$auth=$row['auth'];
if($count==1){
    if($auth==1){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['auth']=$auth;
        $_SESSION['u_name']=$myusername;
        header("location:index.php");
    }
    elseif($auth==0){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['auth']=$auth;
        header("location:calendar.php");
    }
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

And at the top of the other pages that you don't want the user to see put something like

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['auth']!=1){
    header("location:login.php");
}
```

Comment: I didn't use your code but I'm sure you might be able to piece it together.